# Jquery using function to return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

1. Created a JS function to add two numbers in index.js

   ```
   function add(number1, number2) {
   var num1 = parseInt(number1);
   var num2 = parstInt(number2);
   var num3 = num1.num2;
   return num3;
   }
   ```
2. Created a html page in Visual Studio

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js">     
</script>
<script src="index.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Adding two numbers </h1>
<input id="num1" placeholder="0" />
<input id="num2" placeholder="0" />
<button id="btnAdd" type="button"> Add</button>
<input id="total" placeholder="0" readonly />
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('document').ready(function () {
           $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
               $('#total').val(add(num1, num2));
       });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When we click on "Add" button, total should be displayed
But nothing happens with this code

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with `num1.num2`?  How do you set `num1` and `num2` when calling `add(num1, num2)` inside the jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declared `num1` and `num2` when you're calling `add`. Make your code this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        $('#total').val(add($("#num1").val(), $("#num2").val()));
    });
});
```

And it should work.

EDIT: Change your `add` function to this:

```
function add(number1, number2) {
    var num1 = parseInt(number1);
    var num2 = parseInt(number2);
    var num3 = num1 + num2;
    return num3;
}
```

The `.` operator doesn't add two numbers.

Comment: $('document').ready(function () {
           $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
               $('#total').val(add($("#num1").val(), $("#num2").val()));
                   //$('#total').val(add(num1, num2));
           });

        });

Comment: still the same result

Comment: OK, I'll edit my post with what I believe to be the correct code.

Comment: $('document').ready(function () {
           $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
                   $('#total').val(add($("#num1").val(), $("#num2").val()));
                   //$('#total').val(add(num1, num2));
           });

        });

Comment: @SudhirJangam Fixed now, any better?

Comment: var num3 = num1 + num2;

Comment: Corrected the addition line, but no change

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors on your code:

**1)** you have to get values from the `inputs` elements.

**2)** You have a typo error on one of the `parseInt()` methods.

**3)** To adds number you where using `.`? Should no be the `+` operator.

Check the next example with the fixes:

```js
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#btnAdd').click(function ()
    {
        var num1 = $("#num1").val();
        var num2 = $("#num2").val();
        $('#total').val(add(num1, num2));
    });
});

function add(number1, number2)
{
    var num1 = parseInt(number1);
    var num2 = parseInt(number2);
    var num3 = num1 + num2;
    return num3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> Adding two numbers </h1>
<input id="num1" placeholder="0" />
<input id="num2" placeholder="0" />
<button id="btnAdd" type="button"> Add</button>
<input id="total" placeholder="0" readonly />
```

Comment: Um, where are the typos in the `parseInt()` methods in the OP's code? It looks fine to me.

Comment: this one: `parstInt(number2);`

Comment: I changed the code as below, still no change                                                                                                                 var num1 = $("#num1").val();
      var num2 = $("#num2").val();
      $('#total').val(add(num1, num2));

Comment: @JackBashford I also won't note it if wasn't for the help of the console debug from the snippet tool.

Comment: I corrected the typo in parseInt, now it's working, thanks both of you

Comment: @SudhirJangam I recommend to inspect the developer console debug of your browser more often, it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#btnAdd').click(function ()
    {
        var num1 = ( $("#num1").val()==""?0:$("#num1").val());
        var num2 = ( $("#num2").val()==""?0:$("#num2").val());
        $('#total').val(add(num1, num2));
    });
});

function add(number1, number2)
{
    var num1 = parseInt(number1);
    var num2 = parseInt(number2);
    var num3 = num1 + num2;
    return num3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> Adding two numbers </h1>
<input id="num1" placeholder="0" />
<input id="num2" placeholder="0" />
<button id="btnAdd" type="button"> Add</button>
<input id="total" placeholder="0" readonly />
```

Maybe an exception if the input is empty is necesary for your problem

```
( $("#num1").val()==""?0:$("#num1").val());
```